# Constructing NameOf expression via SyntaxFactory (Roslyn)

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Trying to construct `nameof` expression from scratch using C# `SyntaxFactory`. Roslyn fails to recognize my `InvocationExpressionSyntax` as a contextual `nameof` keyword and throws error diagnostics upon `Emit` command.

Tried to give Roslyn valid code to parse in hope that I'll find differences between my syntax construct and the "correctly parsed one". I was able to track the difference down to "nameof" identifier token, but that's where I got stuck. I can't find any difference between my `nameof` token and the parsed one, yet they are still somehow different.

When I use the "parsed one" everything works and `Emit` works as expected, without errors. On the other hand, when I use my own `nameof` token, it fails to compile and `Emit` throws error diagnostics.

Code I was testing it on:

```
var CODE = "class X { void Q() { var q = nameof(Q); } }";

var correctSyntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(CODE);
var correctRoot = correctSyntaxTree.GetRoot();
var correctNameOf = correctRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>().First();

var correctExpression = (IdentifierNameSyntax)correctNameOf.Expression;

var myNameOf = SyntaxFactory.InvocationExpression (
    correctExpression, //Works
    //SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("nameof"), //Doesn't work
    //SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.NameOfKeyword)), //System.ArgumentException: 'identifier'

    //SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(correctExpression.Identifier), //Works
    //SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(correctExpression.Identifier.ValueText), //Doesn't work

    //correctExpression.WithIdentifier(SyntaxFactory.Identifier("nameof")), //Doesn't work
    //correctExpression.WithIdentifier(SyntaxFactory.Identifier(correctExpression.Identifier.ValueText)), //Doesn't work

    //SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("nameof").WithTriviaFrom(correctExpression), //Doesn't work
    //correctExpression.CopyAnnotationsTo(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("nameof")), //Doesn't work
    //SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(correctExpression.Identifier.WithoutAnnotations().WithoutTrivia()), //Works

    SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList (
        SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList (
            SyntaxFactory.Argument (
                SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("Q")
            )
        )
    )
);

var newRoot = correctRoot.ReplaceNode(correctNameOf, myNameOf);
var newTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.Create((CSharpSyntaxNode)newRoot);

var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create (
    "Compilation",
    new[] { newTree },
    references: MsCorLib,
    options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
);

var compilationResult = compilation.Emit(new MemoryStream());
```

Could anyone point out any difference between the parsed token and my token, which is causing the Roslyn to (correctly) not be able to bind the `nameof` expression to any "in-code" symbol, yet not treat it as contextual keyword?

**Compilation error:** (1,30): error CS0103: The name 'nameof' does not exist in the current context

**Compilation#LanguageVersion:** CSharp7

**Roslyn version:** (Nuget newest) Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp v2.3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look into non-private members of `Identifier` you will see that there is property `RawContextualKind`. When you are parsing `nameof` from code, you will get this contextual kind:
[image]

But if you create identifier with `SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("nameof")` you get this:
[image]

In second case, `nameof` is treated as normal identifier and that is why you receive an error. You should use `SyntaxFactory.Identifier()` overload which allows you to specify a contextual kind:

```
SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(
    SyntaxFactory.Identifier(
        SyntaxFactory.TriviaList(),
        SyntaxKind.NameOfKeyword,
        "nameof",
        "nameof",
        SyntaxFactory.TriviaList()))
```

Comment: Oh thank your very much. This made the trick.
I was sniffing around `RawKind` all the time, expecting some contextual difference, but no luck. Since it's not public property, I didn't have a clue about existence of another `ContextualKind`. You showed me yet another Roslyn principle I didn't know of. 
One more thing. Can I somehow read the `ContextualKind` from token (non-reflection way) or is my only chance just guess via `SyntaxFacts.GetContextualKeywordKind(Token.ValueText)`?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way (without using reflection). There is a method `ContextualKind` in `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharpExtensions` but is also internal. Seems to me this was not intendeed to be exposed.